# Drupal Commerce: this hook_form_alter snippet won´t work to hide the postal code of the addressfield. Why?

Tags: commerce, forms

I want to programatically hide the postal code field, of the address module.

I´ve unsuccessfully tried this:

```
function mymodulename_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
if($form_id == 'commerce_checkout_form_checkout') {
hide($form['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['locality_block']['postal_code']);
}
```

It is not working, what´s wrong with that code? Thanks for your help!
Rosamunda

Comment: Did you find the answer? If so, it would be great if you could share it with us :)

Comment: Sadly, no. I just hacked the module (no, I´m not proud of it... but it worked). In case I do find other way, you can be sure I´ll post it (I usually do that anyway, as I´m not a programmer it´s the only way I can give back something to the community :)